# MySQL: Matching columns for year over year

Tags: mysql, join

This is a repost to help clarify my question. I am working with time series data and I need to reference a previous year's data. In excel I would just use a vlookup or index match.

Here is my table

```
+------------+--------------+--------------+------+-------+
| date       | unique_id    | prev_year_id | id   | value |
+------------+--------------+--------------+------+-------+
| 2016-01-01 | 1-2016-01-01 | 1-2015-01-01 |    1 |     7 |
| 2016-01-01 | 2-2016-01-01 | 2-2015-01-01 |    2 |    19 |
| 2016-01-01 | 3-2016-01-01 | 3-2015-01-01 |    3 |     6 |
| 2016-01-01 | 4-2016-01-01 | 4-2015-01-01 |    4 |    13 |
| 2016-01-01 | 5-2016-01-01 | 5-2015-01-01 |    5 |     5 |
| 2017-01-01 | 1-2017-01-01 | 1-2016-01-01 |    1 |    17 |
| 2017-01-01 | 2-2017-01-01 | 2-2016-01-01 |    2 |     8 |
| 2017-01-01 | 3-2017-01-01 | 3-2016-01-01 |    3 |    20 |
| 2017-01-01 | 4-2017-01-01 | 4-2016-01-01 |    4 |     3 |
| 2017-01-01 | 5-2017-01-01 | 5-2016-01-01 |    5 |     0 |
| 2018-01-01 | 1-2018-01-01 | 1-2017-01-01 |    1 |     4 |
| 2018-01-01 | 2-2018-01-01 | 2-2017-01-01 |    2 |    21 |
| 2018-01-01 | 3-2018-01-01 | 3-2017-01-01 |    3 |     7 |
| 2018-01-01 | 4-2018-01-01 | 4-2017-01-01 |    4 |     3 |
| 2018-01-01 | 5-2018-01-01 | 5-2017-01-01 |    5 |     6 |
+------------+--------------+--------------+------+-------+
```

my columns are:

**date**,
**unique_id** (this is the concat of id and date together; primary key),
**prev_year_id** (concat of id and date - interval 1 year),
**id**,
**value**

I need help making a statement to match the prev_year_id to the unique_id and return the value of the rows.

There will be a gap of the first year since there will not be any data to reference, but beyond the first year each prev_year_value will have a match to it's previous year's unique_id

This is what I imagine the end result looking like:

```
+------------+--------------+--------------+------+-------+-----------------+
| date       | unique_id    | prev_year_id | id   | value | prev_year_value |
+------------+--------------+--------------+------+-------+-----------------+
| 2016-01-01 | 1-2016-01-01 | 1-2015-01-01 |    1 |     7 | null            |
| 2016-01-01 | 2-2016-01-01 | 2-2015-01-01 |    2 |    19 | null            |
| 2016-01-01 | 3-2016-01-01 | 3-2015-01-01 |    3 |     6 | null            |
| 2016-01-01 | 4-2016-01-01 | 4-2015-01-01 |    4 |    13 | null            |
| 2016-01-01 | 5-2016-01-01 | 5-2015-01-01 |    5 |     5 | null            |
| 2016-01-01 | 1-2017-01-01 | 1-2016-01-01 |    1 |    17 | 7               |
| 2016-01-01 | 2-2017-01-01 | 2-2016-01-01 |    2 |     8 | 19              |
| 2016-01-01 | 3-2017-01-01 | 3-2016-01-01 |    3 |    20 | 6               |
| 2016-01-01 | 4-2017-01-01 | 4-2016-01-01 |    4 |     3 | 13              |
| 2016-01-01 | 5-2017-01-01 | 5-2016-01-01 |    5 |     0 | 5               |
| 2016-01-01 | 1-2018-01-01 | 1-2017-01-01 |    1 |     4 | 17              |
| 2016-01-01 | 2-2018-01-01 | 2-2017-01-01 |    2 |    21 | 8               |
| 2016-01-01 | 3-2018-01-01 | 3-2017-01-01 |    3 |     7 | 20              |
| 2016-01-01 | 4-2018-01-01 | 4-2017-01-01 |    4 |     3 | 3               |
| 2016-01-01 | 5-2018-01-01 | 5-2017-01-01 |    5 |     6 | 0               |
+------------+--------------+--------------+------+-------+-----------------+
```

And this is the statement I have..

```
SELECT A.*, B.value as 'prev_year_value'
FROM table1 A
INNER JOIN table1 B ON A.current_month_code = B.`prev_year_code
```

The results are very slow to return and it returns the next year's value, not the previous year.

Comment: Please include all data directly in your question, do not post links.

Comment: Done, I am new to actually posting on Stack Overflow, so let me know if there is something else I can provide.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.*, b.`value` as `prev_year_value`
FROM `table1` a
LEFT JOIN `table1` b
ON a.`prev_year_id` = b.`unique_id`
```

Since this is a left join, if there is no result for the "ON" statement, the results will still include the values from `a`, and the `prev_year_value` will end up being null, as you want.

In inner joins like the one you tried, it will only include results, where there is a matchup in both tables

Comment: Thanks, I've got it working. I started with a left join and ran into some other issues because I was trying to do a subquery to not have to create unnecessary views/tables. Now that I've simplified some things, the query is running.